# Loop through 3 different JDBC resultsets

Tags: java, resultset, opencsv, zipoutputstream

I am trying to zip 3 [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files from 3 different tables in single zip file `your_files_12354627.zip`.

So, I've the following method which works fine for zip file generation with 1 csv file in it. I'm trying to do this for multiple files and hence I've modified the below code (as shown below the working code):

**WORKING CODE BELOW:**

```
public void sendMessage(String msg) throws DaoException {

    DataSource ds = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmtEmployee = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmtCompany = null; 
    PreparedStatement pstmBuilding = null; 

    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet resultSetFirst = null;
    ResultSet resultSetSecond = null;
    ResultSet resultSetThird = null;


     String[] parts = msg.split("#");
     String requestID = parts[0].trim();
     String userName = parts[1].trim();
     String applicationName = parts[2].trim();




    try {

        ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
        conn = ds.getConnection();  

        pstmtEmployee = conn.prepareStatement(getPatientEmployeeSQL);
        pstmtEmployee.setString(1, requestID);
        resultSetFirst = pstmtEmployee.executeQuery();

        pstmtCompany = conn.prepareStatement(getCompanySQL);
        pstmtCompany.setString(1, requestID);
        resultSetSecond = pstmtCompany.executeQuery();

        pstmtBuilding = conn.prepareStatement(getBuildingSQL);
        pstmtBuilding.setString(1, requestID);
        resultSetThird = pstmtBuilding.executeQuery();




        Path dir = Paths.get("/srv/custom_users", userName);
        Files.createDirectories(dir);

        OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(dir.resolve("your_files_"+ unixTimestamp +".zip"));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos); 

        Path employeeFile = dir.resolve("employee_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
        Path companyFile = dir.resolve("company_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
        Path buildingFile = dir.resolve("building_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");


        ZipEntry firstEntry = new ZipEntry(employeeFile.getFileName().toString());
        zos.putNextEntry(firstEntry);
        try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))) {
               writer.writeAll(resultSetFirst, true);
               writer.flush();
               zos.closeEntry();
        }

        /*ZipEntry secondEntry = new ZipEntry(companyFile.getFileName().toString());
        zos.putNextEntry(secondEntry);
        try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))) {
               writer.writeAll(resultSetSecond, true);
               writer.flush();
               zos.closeEntry();
        }

        ZipEntry thirdEntry = new ZipEntry(buildingFile.getFileName().toString());
        zos.putNextEntry(thirdEntry);
        try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))) {
               writer.writeAll(resultSetThird, true);
               writer.flush();
               zos.closeEntry();
        }*/




        zos.close();

        }
        catch(Throwable th) {
            throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
        }
        finally {
            //resource Closing statements

        }   



}
```

**MODIFIED CODE BELOW:**

How should I loop through 3 different resultsetsso that I can make use of `writer.writeAll(resultSetFirst, true);`, `writer.writeAll(resultSetSecond, true);` and `writer.writeAll(resultSetThird, true);` respectively? I am trying to loop through the file names as shown in the code below but not sure how should I handle different result sets inside the for loop as shown below. I've commented at the location where I'm trying to figure out this loop thing.

```
public void sendMessage(String msg) throws DaoException {

    DataSource ds = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmtEmployee = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmtCompany = null; 
    PreparedStatement pstmBuilding = null; 

    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet resultSetFirst = null;
    ResultSet resultSetSecond = null;
    ResultSet resultSetThird = null;


     String[] parts = msg.split("#");
     String requestID = parts[0].trim();
     String userName = parts[1].trim();
     String applicationName = parts[2].trim();




    try {

        ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
        conn = ds.getConnection();  

        pstmtEmployee = conn.prepareStatement(getPatientEmployeeSQL);
        pstmtEmployee.setString(1, requestID);
        resultSetFirst = pstmtEmployee.executeQuery();

        pstmtCompany = conn.prepareStatement(getCompanySQL);
        pstmtCompany.setString(1, requestID);
        resultSetSecond = pstmtCompany.executeQuery();

        pstmtBuilding = conn.prepareStatement(getBuildingSQL);
        pstmtBuilding.setString(1, requestID);
        resultSetThird = pstmtBuilding.executeQuery();




        Path dir = Paths.get("/srv/custom_users", userName);
        Files.createDirectories(dir);

        OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(dir.resolve("your_files_"+ unixTimestamp +".zip"));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos); 

        Path employeeFile = dir.resolve("employee_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
        Path companyFile = dir.resolve("company_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");
        Path buildingFile = dir.resolve("building_custom_file_" + unixTimestamp + ".csv");


        List<String> csvFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
             csvFileNames.add(employeeFile.getFileName().toString());
             csvFileNames.add(companyFile.getFileName().toString());
             csvFileNames.add(buildingFile.getFileName().toString());


        for (String entries : csvFileNames) {

                 ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(entries);
                 zos.putNextEntry(entry);

                 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                 //How should I loop through different resultsets here so that I can make use of writer.writeAll(resultSetFirst, true);
                 // writer.writeAll(resultSetSecond, true); and writer.writeAll(resultSetThird, true); respectively?


                System.out.println("Printing entries");
                System.out.println(entries); 

             }   



        /*ZipEntry firstEntry = new ZipEntry(employeeFile.getFileName().toString());
        zos.putNextEntry(firstEntry);
        try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))) {
               writer.writeAll(resultSetFirst, true);
               writer.flush();
               zos.closeEntry();
        }*/

        /*ZipEntry secondEntry = new ZipEntry(companyFile.getFileName().toString());
        zos.putNextEntry(secondEntry);
        try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))) {
               writer.writeAll(resultSetSecond, true);
               writer.flush();
               zos.closeEntry();
        }

        ZipEntry thirdEntry = new ZipEntry(buildingFile.getFileName().toString());
        zos.putNextEntry(thirdEntry);
        try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))) {
               writer.writeAll(resultSetThird, true);
               writer.flush();
               zos.closeEntry();
        }*/




        zos.close();

        }
        catch(Throwable th) {
            throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
        }
        finally {
            //resource Closing statements

        }   



}
```

Comment: Clarify your question. Are trying to write data from across three tables into a single CSV file? If so, do a JOIN. If not, why combine the three together? Just have three separate methods that each read a table table and write to a file.

Comment: I was trying to zip 3 csv files from 3 different tables in single zip file `your_files_12354627.zip`. The answer below worked for me except for the fact that I had to get rid of `try` block to avoid `Stream Closed` error

Comment: Clarify your Question by editing the body rather than posting as Comments. I did that for you, copying your comment to be the first sentence in the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd suggest you break your code down into several different methods. There's a lot of repetition here.

I'm a bit confused as to whether you're trying to write one ResultSet for each of the files, or all three to each file. A part of this is the files `file`, `fileFacts` and `fileEncounters` which aren't mentioned anywhere else.

If you're trying to put one ResultSet in each Entry, then you could use a Map to map File to ResultSet and then iterate over the Entries or Keys. Something like....

```
....
  Map<String,ResultSet> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
  dataMap.put(file.getFileName().toString(),resultSetFirst);
  dataMap.put(filefacts.getFileName().toString(),resultSetSecond);
  dataMap.put(fileEncounters.getFileName().toString(),resultSetThird);

  for (Map.Entry<String,ResultSet> e : dataMap.entrySet()){
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(e.getKey()));
    try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8))){
      writer.writeAll(e.getValue(), true);
      writer.flush();
      zos.closeEntry();
    }
  }
....
```

But it'd probably easier and clearer to just use a method...

```
....
  makeEntry(zos,file.getFileName().toString(),resultSetFirst);
  makeEntry(zos,filefacts.getFileName().toString(),resultSetSecond);
  makeEntry(zos,fileEncounters.getFileName().toString(),resultSetThird);
....
}

private static void makeEntry(ZipOutputStream zos,String name, ResultSet res) throws SomeExceptions{
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
    try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos,StandardCharsets.UTF_8))){
      writer.writeAll(res, true);
      writer.flush();
      zos.closeEntry();
  }
}
```

This way you don't have to create and populate the map (or list) just to run the same code three times.

You can/should still use a method if you decide to iterate over a map to make things clearer/cleaner:

```
  Map<String,ResultSet> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
  dataMap.put(file.getFileName().toString(),resultSetFirst);
  dataMap.put(filefacts.getFileName().toString(),resultSetSecond);
  dataMap.put(fileEncounters.getFileName().toString(),resultSetThird);

  for (Map.Entry<String,ResultSet> e : dataMap.entrySet()){
    makeEntry(zos, e.getKey(), e.getValue());
  }
...
```

Look for other areas like this to refactor into methods. A decent rule is to consider creating a method every time you think you should cut and paste code.

*Note that none of this code has actually been compiled or run*

Comment: Thanks very much. To clarify the question, I was trying to zip 3 csv files into `your_files_12354627.zip`. I tested your code and just had to get rid of `try` block as that was closing the resources and I was getting Stream closed error. Once I removed it, it started working fine. Thanks